# Execution requests n times with Postman

Tags: json, postman, postman-collection-runner

I need to execute a requests n times which in his body has an id value. Collection runner lets executing complete collection n times but I have not found anything for concrete requests.

Request body:

{
   "idEncargo":XXXXXXXX
}

From previous request I get an array with several idEncargo.

Somebody knows about this?

Comment: What do you mean by 'concrete' request?

Comment: Hi Ray, I execute one request where I get a list of idEncargo. Later, I need to execute another request for each idEncargo which I got in previous request.

The test scheme would be:

1. - Request ListaEncargo -> List IdEncargo (idEncargo1, idEncargo2, .., idEncargoN)
2. - Request Encargo(idEncargo1)
3. - Request Encargo(idEncargo2)
...
N+1. -  Request Encargo(idEncargoN)

Answer (score 0):

In your first request, if you get an array with all your idEncargo, you shall save it in a global variable
Then in your second request, you shall loop over this array.

Either inside your second request, if it is possible or if you want to perform the http request for each idEncargo, you could try to use setNextRequest feature (refer to http://blog.getpostman.com/2016/03/23/conditional-workflows-in-postman/)
like doing the following (sorry I'm a beginner in javascript, I just suggest the algorithm):

```
request 1 - get my idEncargo array and set it in global // to bypass if array exists
        set global my_index = 0
        setNextRequest("request 2")
request 2 on idEncargo[my_index]
        in request 2 tests part do:
        my_index ++
        if my_index == max value
            setNextRequest("null") // breaks the loop
        else
            setNextRequest("request 2") // processes the next idEncargo
```

Something like that could work ...

hope that helps

Alexandre